# Splitting a Script Into Multiple Files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a fairly large script and I would like to split it into multiple files to keep it more organised. However, when I do that I'm not sure how to access variables and objects.

Currently everything is in one file *main.py*. I create a class with GUI elements and then I have multiple functions that access the GUI objects, e.g. funcA and funcB. The issue I'm facing is that if I put funcA or funcB into a separate file and then import it into the main script, I cannot use *funcA.py* to access the objects defined in the main script *main.py*.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: You need to do some refactoring, you can't just split the code in separate files as is. If you have a class, you can break it in more classes, use or not inheritance, but one single class in more files...no. Also your question is rather general, a specific answer is difficult to give

Comment: Its very hard to suggest without knowing the complete background. But the follwing things might help.

1) OOP is not mandatory, Use if it is required else just have functions.
2) Do a logical breakdown(based on functionality), this will help you figure the files/packages structure
3) Try to parameterise all the functions/classes, this will help you understand the contract between the APIs better
4) Don't try to optimize and refactor at the same time, might not work very well and can take more time.